# Why is my position:sticky not working?

Tags: html, css

I want my navigation bar to be sticky, but it's not working. I'm also using some basic jQuery to toggle slidedown for class "dropmenu". I also tried position sticky for `<a>` element and still it wouldn't work.
This is HTML and CSS :

```css
.dropmenu {
  display: block;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("images/menuicon.png") no-repeat 98% center;
  background-color: #404040;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #505050;
  display: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

div.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="center">
        <header>
            <img class="headerImage" src="images/header.png"/>
            <hr class="menu">
            <div class="sticky">
                <a class="dropmenu"></a>
                <nav class="desktop">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Sertet</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Rtretrti</a></li>
                        <li><a href="photos.php">ertettterli</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php">retemi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Kerterti</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            </header>
        <hr class="menu">
   <p>content goes here</p>
</div>
```

So what would be the problem?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cofatoyuwu/1/edit?html,css,output — It works when I test it. What browser(s) are you testing in? Do they support the feature?

Comment: Is your sticky div wrapped in a parent element?

Comment: Yes, inside header element which contains picture and this navigation bar below.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you place a `position:sticky` element inside another element things can get tricky. The sticky element will only travel the height of the parent element so you need to have space in your parent element for the sticky element to move because `position: sticky` is scoped to the parent element and not the page. The parents overflow and display property can also have an effect. You can try to set the display property of your parent elements to `display: intital`.

try adding the following:

```
.center, header{
  display:initial;
}
```

You can probably set it to inline or inline-block as well depending on your needs.

Here is your snippet with that added along with a couple of other things just for display purposes:

```css
body{
  height:200vh;
}

.center, header{
  display:initial;
}

.dropmenu {
  display: block;
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("images/menuicon.png") no-repeat 98% center;
  background-color: #404040;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #505050;
  display: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

div.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100px; background:green;"></div>
    
    <div class="center">
        <header>
            <img class="headerImage" src="images/header.png"/>
            <hr class="menu">
            <div class="sticky">
                <a class="dropmenu"></a>
                <nav class="desktop">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Sertet</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Rtretrti</a></li>
                        <li><a href="photos.php">ertettterli</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php">retemi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Kerterti</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            </header>
        <hr class="menu">
   <p>content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

Usually, it's because of some parent's "overflow" property.

If any parent/ancestor of the sticky element has any of the following overflow properties set, **position: sticky** won't work:

- overflow: hidden
- overflow: scroll
- overflow: auto

Here's what helped me. Simply copy/paste the following snippet into your browser's console. This will help you to identify all parent elements with overflow property set to something other than visible:

```
    // Change to your STICKY element
    let parent = document.querySelector('.sticky').parentElement;
    
    while (parent) {
        const hasOverflow = getComputedStyle(parent).overflow;
        if(hasOverflow !== 'visible') {
            console.log(hasOverflow, parent);
        }
        parent = parent.parentElement;
    }
```

Then it's mostly the issue of setting the right overflow property to the right element.

Answer (score 8):

It's not the solution to **this** specific problem, but in case it helps somebody.

I accidentally removed the `top` CSS rule when refactoring the code, adding it back did the trick for me:

```
.my-elem {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, I found that `overflow: hidden;` on a parent container was what was breaking the child's `position: sticky;`. If overflow on the parent is visible, the sticky starts working.

Comment: Exactly. And it's not just a direct parent! Any parent above will break the sticky property.

Comment: This is exactly where the problems of sticky position come from. We often set overflow:hidden to the parrent (especially body tag) cause to disable also sticky position. Just remove overflow:hidden or make it visibility and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had no parent elements with overflow so my solution was this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```